# Grails- how to get the value of specific input through <g:set> in the gsp

Tags: grails, gsp

I have the following input:

```
  <input type="text" class="signup-input invitee" rows="1" id="invite${i}" name="invitees[${i}].user" data-partInvitee="${i}" placeholder="Enter name"/>
```

I want to use , but I don't know how to get the value of the input.

```
<g:set var="currentVal" value="???"/>
```

Comment: What are you going to use "currentVal" for?

Comment: @Lewis Norton - to verify if the input is empty or not

Comment: What do you want to happen when the input is empty? And conversely what about when it is populated?

Comment: @Lewis Norton - in case it is empty I want to add some class

Comment: If you want to do this check in gsp only when the page loads then you can do something like <input value="${foo}" class="${foo?:'empty'}"/>. Otherwise you will need to use Javascript to check each time the value of the input is changed and add/remove the classes depending on whether the input is found to be empty.

Comment: You can also use the built in "required" tag attribute. E.G., <input name="myInput" id="test" required/>. When this input is empty the ":required" selector is applied to the CSS. So the style in #test:required{} will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the value of the input using g:set as gsps are rendered on the server before being shown in the browser. The value of the input can change after "currentVal" has been set.

You will need to use Javascript to solve this problem.